# SQL Join query successfully converts into JSON but how do I interact with it?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, json, join

I have an SQL Join on two tables below:

```
_____Persons_____
name: "Joe"
age: 28
job_id: 0

_____Jobs_____
job_id: 0
job_title: "Farmer"

"SELECT * FROM Persons INNER JOIN Jobs ON Persons.job_id = Jobs.job_id"
```

Then I convert the SQL output into JSON with C# System.Web.Script.Serialization... The output of which is a JSON object:

```
var personal_report = [{"name":"Joe", "age":28, "Persons.job_id":0, "Jobs.job_id":0, "job_title:"Farmer"}]
```

This is great, but when I go to access the JSON object, I cannot use "job_id". Perhaps my syntax is off?

```
personal_report[0].name             // outputs "Joe"
personal_report[0].job_title        // outputs "Farmer"
personal_report[0].job_id           // error
personal_report[0].Persons.job_id   // error
personal_report[0].Jobs.job_id      // error
```

How can I access that attribute? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the Exception error + Deserialization code ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the properties of the JSON object in JavaScript or C#?

Comment: `personal_report[0]['Jobs.job_id']`, but yuck, use some `AS` in your SQL to clean that up...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis! That worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in your JSON contains `.` characters and therefore you cannot access it directly. You can use `[]` notation to access properties by string like this:

```
personal_report[0]['Persons.job_id']; // 0
personal_report[0]['Jobs.job_id']; // 0
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As madox2 suggests or the following sql will make `.job_id` "visible"

```
SELECT name, age, persons.job_id as job_id, job_title
FROM Persons 
INNER JOIN Jobs ON Persons.job_id = Jobs.job_id
```